# Riesz representation theorem on Hilbert space with equivalent norms

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, riesz-representation-theorem

If we have a Hilbert space that has two equivalent norms (and inner products), are the Riesz maps (from Riesz representation theorem) associated with each inner product the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Note:** of course, it fails already in $\mathbb{C}$. Just consider $(z,w)=z\overline{w}$ and $(z,w)'=2z\overline{w}$. And you see how to generalize this dilation idea. But I thought it could be more interesting to give the slightly more general viewpoint below.

If $(x,y)$ is one inner product and if $P$ is invertible in $B(H)$, then 
$$
(x,y)':=(Px,Py)
$$
is an equivalent inner product. If $P$ is not an isometry for the latter, take $x$ such that $\|Px\|\neq \|x\|$. Then
$$
(x,x)'=(Px,Px)=\|Px\|^2\neq \|x\|^2=(x,x).
$$
In particular, the functionals $(x,\cdot )'$ and $(x,\cdot )$ are distinct.

Comment: Hmm. But your norm on the left of the $\neq$ sign is with respect to $(\cdot,\cdot)'$ and the norm on the right of the sign is wrt. the original inner product.

Comment: Consider $P$ constant > 0 .

Comment: @aere No. The only thing that is wrt to the new inner product is $(x,x)'$. By definition, this is $(Px,Px)$ in the old inner product.

Comment: Thanks. If P is non-zero constant, then it seems to be OK?

Comment: @aere Yes $P$ scalar $P=cI$ with $c\neq 0$ is the example I gave at the beginning. I just added the rest because it is a standard way to build new inner products from old ones, so I thought you would find it interesting. Do you understand the argument, now?

Comment: @aere Yes, it works for $P=cI$ with $c\neq 0$ and $c\neq \pm 1$. But it works more generally for any $P$ invertible, non isometric.

Comment: Thanks for your patience. I'm a bit confused when you say "it  works" -- you mean the riesz maps fail to be the same presumably. In your example, with $P=2$, I am just thinking about why that must mean the functionals are different. Sorry for my slowness.

Comment: @aere Yes, when I say it works, I mean it provides counterexample. For $P=2Id$ (not $2$, that's a umber, not a map), we get $(x,y)'=(2x,2y)=4(x,y)$ which is obviously not equal to $(x,y)$.